# PASS_THROUGH_EXCEPTIONS constant(s) usage in test cases?

Tags: ruby, jruby, testunit

Can someone please explain usage of `PASS_THROUGH_EXCEPTIONS`, `NOT_PASS_THROUGH_EXCEPTIONS`, `NOT_PASS_THROUGH_EXCEPTIONS_NAMES` in test-unit gem ? Can they be customized?

Comment: Where do you see constants? I do not see them when searching the Watir-Webdriver code.

Comment: Hi Jastin, sorry for the inconvinience, they are part of test unit gem.